# Uconvert json response to CSV file

Tags: python, json, csv

i have the below json response.

```
{"userId":"vendor","sessionId":"3d716be43d094fefa2261b5347a6127f","channelName":"/omsevents/usession/3d716be43d094fefa2261b5347a6127f","fadList":["NERemoteConfig","ShowSWStatus","esm_modify_erp","ManageStaticLink","ForceActivateSw","GetNeTime","AlarmDebounceModify","SetMeTime","DeleteME","esm_prov_tunnel","CreateJob","GlobalAlignDownwards","esm_prov_mclag","removeSubnet","MapNodeMovement","ModifyRNEIndex","ViewSwdlJobReport","GetSwPkg","AdvancedConstruct","wdm_performanceManagementFunction","Map_FUNCTION_admin_operator","ManageNEInventory","GetNeList","OSAddressRW","ShowInformations","SwStatusSwdlJob","CreateSwdlSession","RunPerfMon_15m","cpb_operationFunction","AbortSwdlSession","Cmd_MapInv_SbnListNodes","F_DELETE_CUSTOMER_TEMPLATE","esm_prov_npa","InternalCmd_MapView_View_ZoomIn","OSAddressRO","Cmd_TM_FUNCTION_allUser","esm_modify_lag","AlignUpwards","DeleteSwdlNes","InternalCmd_MapView_Obj_Undo","ShowBkupSession","CreateDynamicLink","ViewRestoreJobReport","DisplayRI","PathBuild","ManageMonitoring","ShowRestoreNes","ManageMeTime","SysMonRead","DeleteBkpNes","DeleteSwdlSession","RemoveGeneric","ShowSwdlNes","ManageNTP","Cmd_CLOG_Admin_Header_P","ShowEqp","DeleteBkpSession","DeleteRestoreSession","Cmd_CLOG_Admin_Header","ManageNEPopulation","GetSwStatusByType","ShowIsaSWStatus","MEAddressRW","ActivateSw","esm_generate_pm_report","Cmd_Inv_LinkListConnections","Cmd_MapNav_ObjPtrToNPAview","Cmd_CLOG_Ack","MSGUI_FUNCTION_ADMIN_TOPOLOGICALVIEWS","PingNE","esm_modify_mclag","AbortJob","ManualAlignDownwards","Cmd_MapInv_ListTopLevelNtws_PHY_TOPVIEW","Cmd_MapInv_SbnListChildSbns","ShowRestoreSession","Cmd_MapAct_SbnRemoveNode","F_ADD_CUSTOMER_TEMPLATE","ManageAccess","CreateBkupSessionWizard","CreateRestoreSessionWizard","ShowJobList","MigrateME","OpenJobWizard","Cmd_TM_FUNCTION_admin_construct","SysMonAdmin","ModifyLocation","wdm_neManagementFunction","OpenGetSwByTypeWizard","ModifyME","Cmd_MapNav_OpcToMap","NavigationToELM","Cmd_MapAct_SbnDeleteSbnAndSubordinates","AbortNe","Cmd_CLOG_User_Header","MultipleNeDownload","Cmd_TM_FUNCTION_admin_construct_operator","Admin","AddSwdlNes","saveSubnet","wdm_legacyManagementFunction","GetSwdl","Cmd_MapInv_SbnCreateMap","Cmd_MapAct_SbnCommitMapModify","Cmd_MapInv_ListTopLevelNtws_PHY_Test","esm_prov_customer","physconnInNet","UploadRemoteInventory","GetSwDetail","ActiveJob","NEInventory","ManageResynchro","RunPerfMon_hour","Operations","Cmd_MapWiz_ModifySubnet","AbortBkupSession","GetNeLabel","SetNeTime","InternalCmd_MapView_View_ZoomOut","NavigationToEquipments","ManageFilter","ViewBkupJobReport","DeleteSw","wdm_inventoryFunction","ManageLocalAccess","NetworkAddressRW","esm_job_reschedule","AddBkpNes","SysMonView","esm_design_template","Cmd_MapInv_PopulateSbnsInTree_PHY","addSubnet","InternalCmd_MapView_Obj_Redo","Cmd_MapInv_ShowOpcView","NetworkAddressRO","esm_design_feature","InternalCmd_MapView_View_ZoomBestFit","AlarmDebounceView","EditSwdlJobWizard","CreatePartialSwdlJob","ModifyACD","NavigationToURLs","EMLInventory","viewMap","Cmd_TM_FUNCTION_admin","esm_prov_service","Cmd_MapAct_SbnAddNode","DeleteRestoreNes","ActiveSoftware","NavigationToHostNe","AdvancedViewer","wdm_alarmManagementFunction","AllUsers","CreateSUBNE","ShowSwdlSession","EditJob","ManageSupervision","CreateNE","esm_modify_tunnel","ModifyUserLabel","Cmd_MapWiz_SbnCreateSimple","esm_modify_npa","GetNeType","Cmd_MapAct_DataSynchronize","OpenGetSwByNameWizard","InternalCmd_MapView_View_ChangeBackground","ResynchroAll","RunPerfMon_day","MulitpleNeBackup","ModifyComments","CreatePartialSwdlJobFromNeList","F_MODIFY_CUSTOMER_TEMPLATE","ManageLinkInventory","GetFtServer","esm_modify_service","ManageMib","EditRestorJobWizard","esm_deploy_networkConfig","Cmd_EventParameter","ShowJobStatus","ShowStatuses","addNode","Cmd_CLOG_User_Header_P","NavigationToAlarms","InternalCmd_MapView_Obj_Save","EditBkupJobWizard","InternalCmd_MapView_View_SwitchLayer","CreateRestoreSession","esm_job_delete","esm_prov_erp","Cmd_MapCrt_SbnCreate","Cmd_MapInv_ListObjsForCreateSbn","GetSwStatusByName","CreateSwdlSessionWizard","DirInventory","removeNode","ManageAdmin","esm_prov_lag","DeleteJob","CreateBkupSession","wdm_provisionFunction","ManageClone","modifySubnet","CommitSw","CreateME","ShowAlarms","InternalCmd_MapView_View_NormalSize","CreateRNE","InternalCmd_MapView_View_Miniature","ShowBackupNes","Construct","Cmd_Inv_SbnListPhyconnections","NERemoteConfig","ShowSWStatus","esm_modify_erp","ManageStaticLink","ForceActivateSw","GetNeTime","AlarmDebounceModify","SetMeTime","DeleteME","esm_prov_tunnel","CreateJob","GlobalAlignDownwards","esm_prov_mclag","removeSubnet","MapNodeMovement","ModifyRNEIndex","ViewSwdlJobReport","GetSwPkg","AdvancedConstruct","wdm_performanceManagementFunction","Map_FUNCTION_admin_operator","ManageNEInventory","GetNeList","OSAddressRW","ShowInformations","SwStatusSwdlJob","CreateSwdlSession","RunPerfMon_15m","cpb_operationFunction","AbortSwdlSession","Cmd_MapInv_SbnListNodes","F_DELETE_CUSTOMER_TEMPLATE","esm_prov_npa","InternalCmd_MapView_View_ZoomIn","OSAddressRO","Cmd_TM_FUNCTION_allUser","esm_modify_lag","AlignUpwards","DeleteSwdlNes","InternalCmd_MapView_Obj_Undo","ShowBkupSession","CreateDynamicLink","ViewRestoreJobReport","DisplayRI","PathBuild","ManageMonitoring","ShowRestoreNes","ManageMeTime","SysMonRead","DeleteBkpNes","DeleteSwdlSession","RemoveGeneric","ShowSwdlNes","ManageNTP","Cmd_CLOG_Admin_Header_P","ShowEqp","DeleteBkpSession","DeleteRestoreSession","Cmd_CLOG_Admin_Header","ManageNEPopulation","GetSwStatusByType","ShowIsaSWStatus","MEAddressRW","ActivateSw","esm_generate_pm_report","Cmd_Inv_LinkListConnections","Cmd_MapNav_ObjPtrToNPAview","Cmd_CLOG_Ack","MSGUI_FUNCTION_ADMIN_TOPOLOGICALVIEWS","PingNE","esm_modify_mclag","AbortJob","ManualAlignDownwards","Cmd_MapInv_ListTopLevelNtws_PHY_TOPVIEW","Cmd_MapInv_SbnListChildSbns","ShowRestoreSession","Cmd_MapAct_SbnRemoveNode","F_ADD_CUSTOMER_TEMPLATE","ManageAccess","CreateBkupSessionWizard","CreateRestoreSessionWizard","ShowJobList","MigrateME","OpenJobWizard","Cmd_TM_FUNCTION_admin_construct","SysMonAdmin","ModifyLocation","wdm_neManagementFunction","OpenGetSwByTypeWizard","ModifyME","Cmd_MapNav_OpcToMap","NavigationToELM","Cmd_MapAct_SbnDeleteSbnAndSubordinates","AbortNe","Cmd_CLOG_User_Header","MultipleNeDownload","Cmd_TM_FUNCTION_admin_construct_operator","Admin","AddSwdlNes","saveSubnet","wdm_legacyManagementFunction","GetSwdl","Cmd_MapInv_SbnCreateMap","Cmd_MapAct_SbnCommitMapModify","Cmd_MapInv_ListTopLevelNtws_PHY_Test","esm_prov_customer","physconnInNet","UploadRemoteInventory","GetSwDetail","ActiveJob","NEInventory","ManageResynchro","RunPerfMon_hour","Operations","Cmd_MapWiz_ModifySubnet","AbortBkupSession","GetNeLabel","SetNeTime","InternalCmd_MapView_View_ZoomOut","NavigationToEquipments","ManageFilter","ViewBkupJobReport","DeleteSw","wdm_inventoryFunction","ManageLocalAccess","NetworkAddressRW","esm_job_reschedule","AddBkpNes","SysMonView","esm_design_template","Cmd_MapInv_PopulateSbnsInTree_PHY","addSubnet","InternalCmd_MapView_Obj_Redo","Cmd_MapInv_ShowOpcView","NetworkAddressRO","esm_design_feature","InternalCmd_MapView_View_ZoomBestFit","AlarmDebounceView","EditSwdlJobWizard","CreatePartialSwdlJob","ModifyACD","NavigationToURLs","EMLInventory","viewMap","Cmd_TM_FUNCTION_admin","esm_prov_service","Cmd_MapAct_SbnAddNode","DeleteRestoreNes","ActiveSoftware","NavigationToHostNe","AdvancedViewer","wdm_alarmManagementFunction","AllUsers","CreateSUBNE","ShowSwdlSession","EditJob","ManageSupervision","CreateNE","esm_modify_tunnel","ModifyUserLabel","Cmd_MapWiz_SbnCreateSimple","esm_modify_npa","GetNeType","Cmd_MapAct_DataSynchronize","OpenGetSwByNameWizard","InternalCmd_MapView_View_ChangeBackground","ResynchroAll","RunPerfMon_day","MulitpleNeBackup","ModifyComments","CreatePartialSwdlJobFromNeList","F_MODIFY_CUSTOMER_TEMPLATE","ManageLinkInventory","GetFtServer","esm_modify_service","ManageMib","EditRestorJobWizard","esm_deploy_networkConfig","Cmd_EventParameter","ShowJobStatus","ShowStatuses","addNode","Cmd_CLOG_User_Header_P","NavigationToAlarms","InternalCmd_MapView_Obj_Save","EditBkupJobWizard","InternalCmd_MapView_View_SwitchLayer","CreateRestoreSession","esm_job_delete","esm_prov_erp","Cmd_MapCrt_SbnCreate","Cmd_MapInv_ListObjsForCreateSbn","GetSwStatusByName","CreateSwdlSessionWizard","DirInventory","removeNode","ManageAdmin","esm_prov_lag","DeleteJob","CreateBkupSession","wdm_provisionFunction","ManageClone","modifySubnet","CommitSw","CreateME","ShowAlarms","InternalCmd_MapView_View_NormalSize","CreateRNE","InternalCmd_MapView_View_Miniature","ShowBackupNes","Construct","Cmd_Inv_SbnListPhyconnections"],"nadString":"Voda unknown","userNadRole":"GLOBAL"}
```

i need to convert it to a csv file, each row has the header and below it the value. like this

```
userId    sessionId    channelName            fadList   NEremote  ...
vendor     3d716be..   /omsevents/usession     so on     so on    ...
```

i tried this solution but not working.

```
def json_csv() :

    file = input("Please Enter new CSV file new  :")
    # Opening JSON file and loading the data
    # into the variable data
    with open(r"D:\json.txt") as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)

    employee_data = data

    # now we will open a file for writing
    data_file = open(file,'w')

    # create the csv writer object
    csv_writer = csv.writer(data_file)

    # Counter variable used for writing
    # headers to the CSV file
    count = 0

    for emp in data:
        if count == 0 :

            # Writing headers of CSV file
            header = emp.keys()
            csv_writer.writerow(header)
            count += 1

        # Writing data of CSV file
        csv_writer.writerow(emp.values())

    data_file.close()
json_csv()
```

UPDATE 1 :

Thanks to Hozafya , he provided below solution:

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
x = open("test.txt").readline()
df = json_normalize(x)
df.to_csv("file.csv")
```

the script is working for the first 3 items. starting from the list, all the entire data in a one column. so i need the data to be as following for example.:

[excel sheet example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPaC1.png)

UPDATE 2 :
the solution which provided from Hozayfa solved my issue. just one more last thing, when i attach the json data directly, the script is work fine like below :

```
x = {"userId":"vendor","sessionId":"3d716be43d094fefa2261b5347a6127f","channelName":"/omsevents/usession/3d716be43d094fefa2261b5347a6127f","fadList":["NERemoteConfig","ShowSWStatus","esm_modify_erp","ManageStaticLink","ForceActivateSw","GetNeTime","AlarmDebounceModify","SetMeTime","DeleteME","esm_prov_tunnel","CreateJob","GlobalAlignDownwards","esm_prov_mclag","removeSubnet","MapNodeMovement","ModifyRNEIndex","ViewSwdlJobReport","GetSwPkg","AdvancedConstruct","wdm_performanceManagementFunction","Map_FUNCTION_admin_operator","ManageNEInventory","GetNeList","OSAddressRW","ShowInformations","SwStatusSwdlJob","CreateSwdlSession","RunPerfMon_15m","cpb_operationFunction","AbortSwdlSession","Cmd_MapInv_SbnListNodes","F_DELETE_CUSTOMER_TEMPLATE","esm_prov_npa","InternalCmd_MapView_View_ZoomIn","OSAddressRO","Cmd_TM_FUNCTION_allUser","esm_modify_lag","AlignUpwards","DeleteSwdlNes","InternalCmd_MapView_Obj_Undo","ShowBkupSession","CreateDynamicLink","ViewRestoreJobReport","DisplayRI","PathBuild","ManageMonitoring","ShowRestoreNes","ManageMeTime","SysMonRead","DeleteBkpNes","DeleteSwdlSession","RemoveGeneric","ShowSwdlNes","ManageNTP","Cmd_CLOG_Admin_Header_P","ShowEqp","DeleteBkpSession","DeleteRestoreSession","Cmd_CLOG_Admin_Header","ManageNEPopulation","GetSwStatusByType","ShowIsaSWStatus","MEAddressRW","ActivateSw","esm_generate_pm_report","Cmd_Inv_LinkListConnections","Cmd_MapNav_ObjPtrToNPAview","Cmd_CLOG_Ack","MSGUI_FUNCTION_ADMIN_TOPOLOGICALVIEWS","PingNE","esm_modify_mclag","AbortJob","ManualAlignDownwards","Cmd_MapInv_ListTopLevelNtws_PHY_TOPVIEW","Cmd_MapInv_SbnListChildSbns","ShowRestoreSession","Cmd_MapAct_SbnRemoveNode","F_ADD_CUSTOMER_TEMPLATE","ManageAccess","CreateBkupSessionWizard","CreateRestoreSessionWizard","ShowJobList","MigrateME","OpenJobWizard","Cmd_TM_FUNCTION_admin_construct","SysMonAdmin","ModifyLocation","wdm_neManagementFunction","OpenGetSwByTypeWizard","ModifyME","Cmd_MapNav_OpcToMap","NavigationToELM","Cmd_MapAct_SbnDeleteSbnAndSubordinates","AbortNe","Cmd_CLOG_User_Header","MultipleNeDownload","Cmd_TM_FUNCTION_admin_construct_operator","Admin","AddSwdlNes","saveSubnet","wdm_legacyManagementFunction","GetSwdl","Cmd_MapInv_SbnCreateMap","Cmd_MapAct_SbnCommitMapModify","Cmd_MapInv_ListTopLevelNtws_PHY_Test","esm_prov_customer","physconnInNet","UploadRemoteInventory","GetSwDetail","ActiveJob","NEInventory","ManageResynchro","RunPerfMon_hour","Operations","Cmd_MapWiz_ModifySubnet","AbortBkupSession","GetNeLabel","SetNeTime","InternalCmd_MapView_View_ZoomOut","NavigationToEquipments","ManageFilter","ViewBkupJobReport","DeleteSw","wdm_inventoryFunction","ManageLocalAccess","NetworkAddressRW","esm_job_reschedule","AddBkpNes","SysMonView","esm_design_template","Cmd_MapInv_PopulateSbnsInTree_PHY","addSubnet","InternalCmd_MapView_Obj_Redo","Cmd_MapInv_ShowOpcView","NetworkAddressRO","esm_design_feature","InternalCmd_MapView_View_ZoomBestFit","AlarmDebounceView","EditSwdlJobWizard","CreatePartialSwdlJob","ModifyACD","NavigationToURLs","EMLInventory","viewMap","Cmd_TM_FUNCTION_admin","esm_prov_service","Cmd_MapAct_SbnAddNode","DeleteRestoreNes","ActiveSoftware","NavigationToHostNe","AdvancedViewer","wdm_alarmManagementFunction","AllUsers","CreateSUBNE","ShowSwdlSession","EditJob","ManageSupervision","CreateNE","esm_modify_tunnel","ModifyUserLabel","Cmd_MapWiz_SbnCreateSimple","esm_modify_npa","GetNeType","Cmd_MapAct_DataSynchronize","OpenGetSwByNameWizard","InternalCmd_MapView_View_ChangeBackground","ResynchroAll","RunPerfMon_day","MulitpleNeBackup","ModifyComments","CreatePartialSwdlJobFromNeList","F_MODIFY_CUSTOMER_TEMPLATE","ManageLinkInventory","GetFtServer","esm_modify_service","ManageMib","EditRestorJobWizard","esm_deploy_networkConfig","Cmd_EventParameter","ShowJobStatus","ShowStatuses","addNode","Cmd_CLOG_User_Header_P","NavigationToAlarms","InternalCmd_MapView_Obj_Save","EditBkupJobWizard","InternalCmd_MapView_View_SwitchLayer","CreateRestoreSession","esm_job_delete","esm_prov_erp","Cmd_MapCrt_SbnCreate","Cmd_MapInv_ListObjsForCreateSbn","GetSwStatusByName","CreateSwdlSessionWizard","DirInventory","removeNode","ManageAdmin","esm_prov_lag","DeleteJob","CreateBkupSession","wdm_provisionFunction","ManageClone","modifySubnet","CommitSw","CreateME","ShowAlarms","InternalCmd_MapView_View_NormalSize","CreateRNE","InternalCmd_MapView_View_Miniature","ShowBackupNes","Construct","Cmd_Inv_SbnListPhyconnections","NERemoteConfig","ShowSWStatus","esm_modify_erp","ManageStaticLink","ForceActivateSw","GetNeTime","AlarmDebounceModify","SetMeTime","DeleteME","esm_prov_tunnel","CreateJob","GlobalAlignDownwards","esm_prov_mclag","removeSubnet","MapNodeMovement","ModifyRNEIndex","ViewSwdlJobReport","GetSwPkg","AdvancedConstruct","wdm_performanceManagementFunction","Map_FUNCTION_admin_operator","ManageNEInventory","GetNeList","OSAddressRW","ShowInformations","SwStatusSwdlJob","CreateSwdlSession","RunPerfMon_15m","cpb_operationFunction","AbortSwdlSession","Cmd_MapInv_SbnListNodes","F_DELETE_CUSTOMER_TEMPLATE","esm_prov_npa","InternalCmd_MapView_View_ZoomIn","OSAddressRO","Cmd_TM_FUNCTION_allUser","esm_modify_lag","AlignUpwards","DeleteSwdlNes","InternalCmd_MapView_Obj_Undo","ShowBkupSession","CreateDynamicLink","ViewRestoreJobReport","DisplayRI","PathBuild","ManageMonitoring","ShowRestoreNes","ManageMeTime","SysMonRead","DeleteBkpNes","DeleteSwdlSession","RemoveGeneric","ShowSwdlNes","ManageNTP","Cmd_CLOG_Admin_Header_P","ShowEqp","DeleteBkpSession","DeleteRestoreSession","Cmd_CLOG_Admin_Header","ManageNEPopulation","GetSwStatusByType","ShowIsaSWStatus","MEAddressRW","ActivateSw","esm_generate_pm_report","Cmd_Inv_LinkListConnections","Cmd_MapNav_ObjPtrToNPAview","Cmd_CLOG_Ack","MSGUI_FUNCTION_ADMIN_TOPOLOGICALVIEWS","PingNE","esm_modify_mclag","AbortJob","ManualAlignDownwards","Cmd_MapInv_ListTopLevelNtws_PHY_TOPVIEW","Cmd_MapInv_SbnListChildSbns","ShowRestoreSession","Cmd_MapAct_SbnRemoveNode","F_ADD_CUSTOMER_TEMPLATE","ManageAccess","CreateBkupSessionWizard","CreateRestoreSessionWizard","ShowJobList","MigrateME","OpenJobWizard","Cmd_TM_FUNCTION_admin_construct","SysMonAdmin","ModifyLocation","wdm_neManagementFunction","OpenGetSwByTypeWizard","ModifyME","Cmd_MapNav_OpcToMap","NavigationToELM","Cmd_MapAct_SbnDeleteSbnAndSubordinates","AbortNe","Cmd_CLOG_User_Header","MultipleNeDownload","Cmd_TM_FUNCTION_admin_construct_operator","Admin","AddSwdlNes","saveSubnet","wdm_legacyManagementFunction","GetSwdl","Cmd_MapInv_SbnCreateMap","Cmd_MapAct_SbnCommitMapModify","Cmd_MapInv_ListTopLevelNtws_PHY_Test","esm_prov_customer","physconnInNet","UploadRemoteInventory","GetSwDetail","ActiveJob","NEInventory","ManageResynchro","RunPerfMon_hour","Operations","Cmd_MapWiz_ModifySubnet","AbortBkupSession","GetNeLabel","SetNeTime","InternalCmd_MapView_View_ZoomOut","NavigationToEquipments","ManageFilter","ViewBkupJobReport","DeleteSw","wdm_inventoryFunction","ManageLocalAccess","NetworkAddressRW","esm_job_reschedule","AddBkpNes","SysMonView","esm_design_template","Cmd_MapInv_PopulateSbnsInTree_PHY","addSubnet","InternalCmd_MapView_Obj_Redo","Cmd_MapInv_ShowOpcView","NetworkAddressRO","esm_design_feature","InternalCmd_MapView_View_ZoomBestFit","AlarmDebounceView","EditSwdlJobWizard","CreatePartialSwdlJob","ModifyACD","NavigationToURLs","EMLInventory","viewMap","Cmd_TM_FUNCTION_admin","esm_prov_service","Cmd_MapAct_SbnAddNode","DeleteRestoreNes","ActiveSoftware","NavigationToHostNe","AdvancedViewer","wdm_alarmManagementFunction","AllUsers","CreateSUBNE","ShowSwdlSession","EditJob","ManageSupervision","CreateNE","esm_modify_tunnel","ModifyUserLabel","Cmd_MapWiz_SbnCreateSimple","esm_modify_npa","GetNeType","Cmd_MapAct_DataSynchronize","OpenGetSwByNameWizard","InternalCmd_MapView_View_ChangeBackground","ResynchroAll","RunPerfMon_day","MulitpleNeBackup","ModifyComments","CreatePartialSwdlJobFromNeList","F_MODIFY_CUSTOMER_TEMPLATE","ManageLinkInventory","GetFtServer","esm_modify_service","ManageMib","EditRestorJobWizard","esm_deploy_networkConfig","Cmd_EventParameter","ShowJobStatus","ShowStatuses","addNode","Cmd_CLOG_User_Header_P","NavigationToAlarms","InternalCmd_MapView_Obj_Save","EditBkupJobWizard","InternalCmd_MapView_View_SwitchLayer","CreateRestoreSession","esm_job_delete","esm_prov_erp","Cmd_MapCrt_SbnCreate","Cmd_MapInv_ListObjsForCreateSbn","GetSwStatusByName","CreateSwdlSessionWizard","DirInventory","removeNode","ManageAdmin","esm_prov_lag","DeleteJob","CreateBkupSession","wdm_provisionFunction","ManageClone","modifySubnet","CommitSw","CreateME","ShowAlarms","InternalCmd_MapView_View_NormalSize","CreateRNE","InternalCmd_MapView_View_Miniature","ShowBackupNes","Construct","Cmd_Inv_SbnListPhyconnections"],"nadString":"Voda unknown","userNadRole":"GLOBAL"}
```

but if i did that :

```
x = open(r'D:\json.txt').readline()
```

i get this error :

```
D:\Python\My Projects\venv\Scripts\python.exe" C:/Users/ahmedabd/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.1/scratches/scratch_9.py
C:/Users/ahmedabd/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.1/scratches/scratch_9.py:4: FutureWarning: pandas.io.json.json_normalize is deprecated, use pandas.json_normalize instead
  df = json_normalize(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ahmedabd/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.1/scratches/scratch_9.py", line 4, in <module>
    df = json_normalize(x)
  File "D:\Python\My Projects\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 66, in wrapper
    return alternative(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\My Projects\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_normalize.py", line 274, in _json_normalize
    if any([isinstance(x, dict) for x in y.values()] for y in data):
  File "D:\Python\My Projects\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_normalize.py", line 274, in <genexpr>
    if any([isinstance(x, dict) for x in y.values()] for y in data):
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can easily do that using `pandas`:

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import json
x = open("test.txt").readline()
x = json.loads(x)
df = json_normalize(x)
df = df.explode('fadList')
df.iloc[1:, 0:3] = ""
df.iloc[1:, 4:] = ""
df.to_csv("file.csv")
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
can i insert a text file containing the json data instead of {"userId":"vendor","sessionId ..}
i mean to do that.
file_read = open(r"D:\json.txt").readlines()
x = {file_read}
df = json_normalize(x)
df.to_csv("D:\session.csv")

Comment: Yes, i am saving the jsons in a text fie. so yes i want form a text file

Comment: it worked for the 1st 4 items. userId,sessionId ,channelName.
after that, the script is putting all data in one column. i mean starting from "fadList", i think because fadList is a list not dic ?

Comment: ```fadList``` is a list so you should a long list. what are you expecting to have? please share output so I can help

Comment: @AhmedAbdel-Latif you cant just have empty values, one solution is to use ```explode``` method.

Comment: first i need to thank you for that much efforts. 2nd can we avoid this even if we changed how we view the data in the csv ?

Comment: you want to avoid what? i didnt get you @AhmedAbdel-Latif

Comment: the duplication rows , for userId,sessionId,channelName and userNadRole.

Comment: Thank you Hozayfa, Yes it worked like a charm, you are the best, just one more issue with this,check UPDATE 2 please.

Comment: @AhmedAbdel-Latif what is data? I guess you are trying to convert a string to a dictionary?

Comment: the content of txt file is the same as above ( {"userId":"vendor"," ..blah blahblah ).i just put it in a file

Comment: ```if any([isinstance(x, dict) for x in y.values()] for y in data):``` what is data here? if you open a file and read it you wont get any error. what's causing the error is the line above? ```for y in data``` what is data?

Comment: i do not know, i posted the complete log error, i am working on the provided code. and it does not contain any "data"

Comment: when you read from the file you are getting a string and not a dictionary. This is why you were getting this error. using ```Json``` we convert a string to a dictionary. I hope that's clear @AhmedAbdel-Latif

Comment: Thank you Hozayfa, you are a genius. can i work with this script on any get response json file ?

Comment: thank you :), I would appreciate an upvote and accept it as an answer. this should save any json file to a csv ofcouse.